# Shift a list in Python

Tags: python

How would you shift left a list by x in Python, and fill the empty values with zeros?

shift left by 1

input: `[1, 2, 3, 4]`
output: `[2, 3, 4, 0]`

shift left by 2

input `[1, 2, 3, 4]`
output `[3, 4, 0, 0]`

Comment: `del items[0]; items.append(0)` for a single shift.

Comment: You could use a `collections.deque` with a max_length of 4.

Comment: Ain't such thing as "Python's arrays". This syntax refers to list.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm concerned, there's no 'easy' way, since Python's lists are not constrained by a size, but you can easily implement an algorithm which handles this:

```py
def shift_left(arr, n):
    return arr[n:] + [0 for _ in range(n)]
```

or a bit more consise:

```py
def shift_left(arr, n):
    return arr[n:] + [0] * n
```

Comment: Ain't such thing as "Python's arrays". This syntax refers to list.

Comment: Not as if it makes too much of a difference... but sure, I'll change the answer to use the correct nomenclature.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine numpy's `append` and `roll` methods:

```py
import numpy as np


def shift_left(x_, r):
    return np.append(np.roll(x_, -r)[:-r], [0 for _ in range(0, r)])


print(shift_left([1, 2, 3, 4], 1))
print(shift_left([1, 2, 3, 4], 2))
```

Result:

```sh
[2 3 4 0]
[3 4 0 0]
```

**Explanation**

---

When you use `roll` on a list:

```py
print(np.roll([1, 2, 3, 4], -2))
```

Result:

```py
[3 4 1 2]
```

You move the each element to the left by `r` times (`r`= -2). But we don't want the last `r` elements so:

```py
print(np.roll([1, 2, 3, 4], -2)[:-2])
```

Result:

```py
[3 4]
```

We want the last `r` values to be 0. So we can append `r` 0 to the end of the array.

```py
print(np.append(np.roll([1, 2, 3, 4], -2)[:-2], [0 for _ in range(0, 2)]))
```

Result:

```py
[3 4 0 0]
```

Comment: I've missed the `return` keyword, now it is returning the actual result.

Answer (score 1):

You can concat two lists as:

```
arr[shift:]+[0]*shift
```

Or if you are a fan of chaining like me:

```
arr[shift:].__add__([0]*shift)
```