# Shift values to right and filling with zero

Tags: python, arrays, list, matrix

I have a list and I want the values to be shifted to right by 1 position and fill the index 0 with a value of 0.

For eg:

```
a = [8,9,10,11]

output = [0,8,9,10]
```

I tried the following:

```
a.insert(0,a.pop())
```

And the above line of code shifted to right and put the last element back at first.

```
a = [11,8,9,10]
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: `a = [0] + a[:-1]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shift a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65100289/shift-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
a = [8, 9, 10, 11]

a.pop()
a.insert(0, 0)
print(a)
```

**Output**

```
[0, 8, 9, 10]
```

Just insert `0` at index `0`.

**A note on performance**

If you are planning on performing this operation multiple times, I suggest you use a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) so insert ([`appendleft`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque.appendleft) in `deque`) and pop is `O(1)` instead of `O(n)`:

```
from collections import deque

a = [8, 9, 10, 11]

d = deque(a)
d.pop()
d.appendleft(0)

print(d)
```

**Output**

```
deque([0, 8, 9, 10]) # list(d) if needed
```

See more on the time complexities of the operations [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Comment: A note on deque--if your list is supposed to be a fixed length, specifying `maxlen` will save you from having to perform the `pop()` step. E.g., `d = deque(a, 4)`

Answer (score 1):

Using [`np.roll`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html).

```
import numpy as np
a = [8, 9, 10, 11]
a[-1] = 0
a = np.roll(a, 1)
# [0, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a.insert(0,a.pop())
```

This says to insert the value of `a.pop()` (the last element of the list) at index `0` in the array. So you shouldn't be surprised at the result. If you want to insert a `0`, then you should specify it directly:

```
a.insert(0, 0)
```